# Masking input in react managed by state

Tags: reactjs, input, web-applications, state, masking

I have a code where I try to mask my phone input so it will look good, here is how it formats the phone:

```
onPhoneChange = (e) => {
            const phone = e.target.value
            if(!phone || phone.match(/^\((\d{2})\) (\d{5})\-(\d{4})$/)){
                this.setState({ phone })
            }else if(!phone || phone.match(/^\d{1,11}?$/)){
                this.setState(() => ({ phone })) 
                if(this.state.phone || this.state.phone.match(/^\d{11}$/)){
                    let formattedPhone
                    let cleaned = ('' + phone).replace(/\D/g, '')
                    let match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})$/)
                    if (match) {
                        formattedPhone = `(${(match[1])}) ${match[2]}-${match[3]}`
                    }
                    this.setState({ phone: formattedPhone })
             }
        }
    }
```

And the value for the input is just the state, which is set like above, I've figured that the setState function is asynchronous, so, when the input gets formatted, it changes visually but internally it conflicts. How would I go around that without using an outside module?

Adding, this is the input:

```
<input
   value={this.state.phone}
   onChange={this.onPhoneChange}
/>
```

Comment: There are many masked inputs available such as react-text-mask. Are these not an option for you?

Comment: I have tried, but when it went with the state component they broke, first input they get is always a ' ', an that seems to make an error. I'll give another try, but I wanted to make something on my own, improve my scripting.